# How Heaviside step function changes limits of integration

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, convolution

This question involves the Laplace transform of the convolution of two functions. The derivation in my textbook has a step that really confuses me. First I'll lay out their argument.

$$ f(t) = f_1(t) \otimes f_2(t) = \int_0^t f_1(t - \tau) f_2(\tau) \, d\tau $$
and it goes on to show that $$\mathscr L[f(t)] = F(s) = F_1(s)F_2(s)$$

Apparently their definition of convolution differs from other contexts as well (this is electrical engineering).

It starts with $$ \mathscr L[f(t) = \int_0^\infty \bigg[ \int_0^t f_1(t - \tau) f_2(\tau) \, d\tau \bigg]e^{-st} \, dt$$

and claims that by introducing $u(t - \tau)$ we can change the limits of the bracketed integral, becoming
$$ \mathscr L[f(t) = \int_0^\infty \bigg[ \int_0^\infty f_1(t - \tau)u(t - \tau) f_2(\tau) \, d\tau \bigg]e^{-st} \, dt $$

My question is how does this allow us to go from $\int_0^t$ to $\int_0^\infty$? I have trouble understanding how we know to go from $0$ to $t$ to begin with (this pops up in solving RC differential equations, for example), but what exactly is the logic that allows us to achieve the last form?

I understand that, for example $\int_0^\infty u(t-2)dt = \int_2^\infty 1 dt$, so how can we change the upper limit? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Heaviside function kills off the portion that is greater than $t$. If $t-\tau < 0$ (i.e. $\tau>t$) then $u(t-\tau) = 0$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Yes, I think I do. I'm so used to thinking in terms of t that I had a hard time figuring out the effects of the step function. I'm still a little fuzzy on how the two can still be equal but I'm sure with a little more thought I'll have convinced myself. Thanks, I knew it would be pretty simple.